# What command APDU should be sent to read binary of an transparent EF?

Tags: smartcard, gsm, apdu, sim-card

So I have given to solve the question below:

A Transparent EF with ID = ‘6F 48’ under DF GSM have data with 10 bytes in length. The terminal want to read only the byte number 2 until byte number 7 (the first byte is byte number 0). What APDUs will the terminal send to the card in order to do that?

I have understood that i should use the READ BINARY command as the comman APDU.
After I do some research, i find that that the answer might be ' A0 B0 11/01 00 02 '

However, I am not sure because I am still new and learning about the APDU and GSM.
Do I get the answer right? or do I miss something on it?

Answer (score 4):

Find below a possible answer. I don't have a SIM right for the commands to be checked , so use it as hints. If you have you CHV1 disable on the SIM card then first command wouldn't be necessary.

```
A020000108XXXXXXXXXXXXXX  -> verify CHV1
A0A40000027F20            -> Select DF GSM
A0A40000026F48            -> Select File
A0B0000206                -> Read 6 bytes from offset 2 (read 2,3,4,5,6,7 bytes)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You *might* be able to combine the last two commands to `A0B0880206` (select by short file identifier `08` in P1 (5 least significant bits of the byte, the topmost bit is the indicator) and offset 02 in P2, but I'm not a SIM card expert.